# Oozie Hive job error on Amazon

Tags: amazon-ec2, hive, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to run a hive job via oozie on amazon using HDP 2.2. 
The user running the job is ec2-user.
When I run a "dryrun" I get the following error :

oozie job -oozie htp://~internal:11000/oozie -config job.properties -dryrun

```
Error: E0803 : E0803: IO error, Encountered ": java .", expected one of ["}", ".", ">", "gt", "<", "lt", "==", "eq", "<=", "le", ">=", "ge", "!=", "ne", "[", "+", "-", "*", "/", "div", "%", "mod", "and", "&&", "or", "||", ":", <IDENTIFIER>, "(", "?"]
```

**Has anyone seen this before?**
Below is my worklfow.

```
<workflow-app name="OozieWorkflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
<start to="load" />
<action name="load">
    <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <job-xml>/user/ec2-user/hive-site-oozie.xml</job-xml>
        <script>/user/ec2-user/loadData.hql</script>
        <file>/user/ec2-user/hive-site-oozie.xml#hive-site-oozie.xml</file>
    </hive>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="kill" />
</action>
<kill name="kill">
    <message>Action failed, error
        message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end" /></workflow-app>
```

My job properties are:

```
nameNode=hdfs://~internal:8020
jobTracker=http://~internal:8050
queueName=default
#oozie.libpath=
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/ec2-user
```

Comment: Don't you forget '</workflow-app>' closing tag? or did you just omitted it in question?

Comment: Sorry, ommited from question edited question

Comment: It seems odd that the error message is about the token 'java', but that string doesn't appear in what you have provided. Is it somewhere in the files you are referencing in your Hive action?

Comment: I get the same error when running a hive-action in Oozie. However, the error is just printed in the error_code and error_message columns and does not fail the job. Running hdp 2.2. Quite weird

Answer (score 2):

I found one cause of this error. At least it was the cause of my weird but harmless EL-error when running oozie jobs.

You include the hive-site.xml on the line

```
<job-xml>/user/ec2-user/hive-site-oozie.xml</job-xml>
```

In hdp2.2 the hive-site.xml contains this element:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.logging.operation.log.location</name>
  <value>${system:java.io.tmpdir}/${system:user.name}/operation_logs</value>
</property>
```

For some reason oozie also evaluates the expressions in the provided job-xml. Notice the ${system:java.io.tmpdir} which is not a valid Oozie EL-expression.

I'm not sure how to avoid this error apart from excluding that value from the provided job-xml

Comment: I had no issues just deleting this NVP from the uploaded hive-site.xml either.  I'm using HDP 2.3 as a point of reference.

Answer (score 2):

As said by [selle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30482612), the problem comes from this property from the hive-site.xml file you provided:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.logging.operation.log.location</name>
  <value>${system:java.io.tmpdir}/${system:user.name}/operation_logs</value>
</property>
```

If you have a specific hive-site.xml file for Oozie (which seems to be the case), you can use an EL-expression that creates the EL-expression.
I replaced this property with this one:

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.logging.operation.log.location</name>
    <value>${'${'}system:java.io.tmpdir}/${'${'}system:user.name}/operation_logs</value>
  </property>
```

It's a bit clumsy but it worked for me!